# How can I add flags included in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, gradlew, autostart

I want to put `myScript.sh` on autostart.

I have set the configuration.

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/myScript.sh
```

And enable it

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/myScript.sh defaults
```

But when I run the `myScript.sh` I get an error because of the flag `-bootRun`. `myScript.sh` looks like this:

```
sudo /home/pi/path/to/my/program/gradlew -bootRun
```

How can I run this script instead?

**Edit:**

I listen to that guy below. I place my code at the `rc.local` at `/etc` in Raspberry.

[image]

But when I run I ge this error. Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your init script is missing quite a bit. Compare it to other files in the same directory. Maybe you'd rather look up [how to run a command on boot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)?

Comment: @thatotherguy I just followed this "manual" https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/run-bash-script-on-startup

Comment: The problem with that is that it'll work poorly with commands that don't exit quickly, and it'll re-run the command when you're shutting down and things like that. Check out the [more upvoted](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/15478) answer on the same question.

Comment: @thatotherguy Ok! I will try that :)

Comment: @thatotherguy See my updated question now.

Comment: That means your command doesn't work. Please make sure the command works independently before you try to run it on boot. Google suggests there shouldn't be a dash in it

Comment: @thatotherguy But I need the bootRun flag and it needs a dash.

Comment: @thatotherguy I used to run the `gradlew` command with `./gradlew -bootRun`. That works.

Comment: Did you actually run `./gradlew bootRun` instead without the dash?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes. But I used cd to direct my self to the `gradlew` file. That solved my problem. Thank you very much for the help. See the answer. As a thank you, I give you this IoT tool. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/JLogger

Comment: Please replace your screenshots with actual text. There are many reasons to NOT use screenshots, most importantly, readers can't search inside of them. Use the `{}` from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to get proper formatting for code/data/errMsgs. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry, I was not able to use mouse at that time. I was using SSH and could not post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thanks to theotherguy above!

[image]